# The operation could not be performed because the library has not been globally initialized

Tags: android, sap-smp

I'm developing an Android application with SAP Mobile Platform 3.0 and local data, the application is able to connect to the OData service, but when I create the Offline store and try to open it throws an ODataException:

> com.sap.smp.client.odata.offline.ODataOfflineException: [-10203] The operation could not be performed because the library has not been globally initialized.

Does anyone know what am I missing? Already tried to look for further information but I couldn't find anything about this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you're initializing global offline store at the start point of your app ...

ODataOfflineStore.globalInit();